# Is this weakly lower semicontinuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Let $X$ Hilbert, consider $B \in L(X)$ strictly positive and self adjoint.
Is the following function weakly lower semicontinuous?

$$|x|_B^2=\langle Bx,x \rangle$$

Notice that

$$|x|_B^2=|B^{1/2}x|^2$$

so |x|_B is a norm, so it is convex, and then it's weakly lower semicontinuous iff it is continuous, which is the case. Am I right?

Comment: You are right. It is continuous, hence weakly lower semi continuous.